# How to handle Too Many Requests (429) error in Mule 4 Process API

Tags: mulesoft, mule4, mule-component

I am new to Mulesoft and need help in resolving the Too Many Requests (429) error thrown when I call my Mule System API /Layer from Mule Process API.

My Mule Process API has below mentioned (screenshot) sub flow to call system API. For each record there are 2 calls made based on if the record is found or not found ((get and Put) or (get and Post)). I have 4000 records to loop.
The workers and worker size are 1 and 0.2vcores for both system and process and can't be increased.

The Mule System API has a rate limit policy set to 10 transactions per second ( to reflect the rate limit of the external system)

How do I control the number of calls made to the system API to avoid Too Many Requests (429) error.

[image]

Comment: Please add the flow as XML text. The image doesn't provide any details of what each component is doing. For more details read the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557)

Comment: Can you change the system API to accept multiple records at once instead of sending each record separately? Does this process needs to be synchronous or can it be done in as async?

Comment: I agree with Harshank, I think you have only two option, either go with queues for Async process in System API, or make changes in System API to accept records at once.

Comment: Hi  Harshank,  This can be Asynchronous. If I change the system API to accept multiple records at once, still I need to handle the outgoing requests going from system API  to external system as they have 10 TPS rate limit. Also there is some additional business logic which process API is doing which also needs to be moved to system API if we take that option.

Comment: In general a client of an API can not control the API intake. Mule doesn't provide any features to implement something like it. See the other comments suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I recently solved this problem by using the "until-successful" scope.
Since "429 - Too Many Requests" leads to an exception in Mule 4, the mentioned scope will repeat itself. You can configure how much time to wait before calling again and max retries.

Comment: An example of how to do this might help the asker understand the solution